# Syntax for "Run Keyword If" on multiple lines for robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am not sure how to write the ELSE IF branch on a new line like in this [example](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If).
I tried to do this:

```
*Variables*
${var}|something

*Test Cases*
test
|Run Keyword If|$var == 'something'|log|something|INFO
|ELSE IF|$var == 'somethingElse'|log|somethingElse|INFO
```

where "|" is a TAB. On running this, I receive this error:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 'Else If' is a reserved keyword. It must be in uppercase (ELSE IF) when used as a marker with 'Run Keyword If'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
Run Keyword If   $var == 'something'   log   something   INFO
...    ELSE IF   $var == 'somethingElse'   log   somethingElse   INFO
```

Switched to spaces based on Bryan's feedback as I don't use pipes myself so would use them incorrectly.

Comment: it doesn't look like that's formatted correctly -- you're using pipes in the middle of the line but not at the start of the line, and the pipes don't have spaces around them.

Comment: apologies, I personally don't use pipes so I was just doing a copy paste of the example given with the question.  Seems like it got Alex in the right direction anyway

Comment: @all - Does it really work? I am using 
<three dots> <tab space>ELSE. It still gives me the error mentioned in the question?
I am using RF3

Comment: @malhar can you paste your code somewhere?  It should indeed work?  Are the dots in line with the Run Keyword If above it?  I purposely space separate as I found issues with tabs, especially when people were using different IDEs.  Try pipes or spaces or something as the delimiter and see if it helps?

Comment: @shicky Here is the  [link] (https://gist.github.com/utkjad/a22a71d4b9787305a2c1#file-exmaple-robot)
Note - There is a comment in the snippet, which is to be ignored. (There is no trailing space)

Comment: @malhar, this does not have the three dots?  What error are you getting?

Comment: @shicky - I am sorry, I confused dots with three spaces. :(  (Damn Sublime!) . Thanks anyway!